# How to mock a class so it doesn't run on import

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I have the following files:

`test_temp.py`:

```
import pytest
from mock import patch

with patch('temp.TheEvilClass'), patch('temp2.TheEvilClass'):
    from temp import TempClass


def test_evil():
    assert True
```

`temp.py`:

```
from temp2 import TheEvilClass

class TempClass(object):
    TheEvilClass()
```

`temp2.py`:

```
class TheEvilClass(object):
    print "I'm evil! ]:>"
    raise Exception
```

My intention was for the patch in `test_temp.py` to mock out `TheEvilClass` so that the exception is never called. I tried patching it in both places, but the exception is still being thrown. Do you have any pointers on what I'm doing wrong and how to test `temp.py` without ever triggering the actual `TheEvilClass`? I tried mocking the whole module (with `patch('temp2')`) but this doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: You can't, you patch *after* import. Instead, you should redesign `temp2` to not do anything on import.

Comment: I disagree with @jonrsharpe , you may not necessarily want to change how the code works just for the purposes of test.  It's more likely a case of needing to set up the environment properly so that imports don't fail.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't really do anything about temp2 since it's an external module.

Comment: And if this external module throws an error on import, how do you use it at all?

Comment: It doesn't throw an error in the runtime environment. I want to create a separate lightweight test environment that doesn't require the bloated runtime env.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do isn't possible with `mock`, because it is the patch itself that triggers the import.  `patch` calls `_get_target` which uses `_importer` which calls `__import__`.

[https://github.com/testing-cabal/mock/blob/master/mock/mock.py#L1206](https://github.com/testing-cabal/mock/blob/b7a77db8b4d4ae34101b2de810f41c2371c2170e/mock/mock.py#L1206)

A simpler way to see that is just by applying the patch directly:

```
patch('temp.TheEvilClass').__enter__()
```

The right way to go about this is to set up the test environment so that unhandled exceptions aren't being raised at import time.

Comment: How is this applyting the patch directly? I don't quite get what I achieve by calling the __enter__() of the patch, after it's being called anyway. And by "setting up the test environment" you mean just suppressing the exception?

Comment: I mean if you use the patch at all (either by directly calling `__enter__`, or by using a `with` statement) then you will see the exception anyway, because *it is the patch action which imports the code*.  If you replace the line `from temp import TempClass` in `test_temp.py` with just `pass` instead, you will understand what I'm describing.  You're going about this the wrong way, it's an XY problem - the correct approach is setting up a test environment to mimic the run-time environment sufficiently well that this code doesn't error out at import time.